# i need to pull crankshaft timing gear on 1996 toyota 1.6 engine

Tags: toyota, corolla

I need to put in front crankshaft seal on 1996 Toyota corolla I have to pull the timing belt gear off the crankshaft to do so I have searched everywhere and haven't found a answer any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Looking at it, the crankshaft timing belt gear is keyed. Most of the time when it's keyed, it is a snug fit, but should be able to pull it directly off by hand. I don't think there's any real way to put a puller on it to take it off. Just wiggle it by hand and see if it will come off.

Comment: IIRC you can use a steering wheel puller, there are two threaded holes. Maybe m8x1.0

Comment: there no threaded holes

Comment: @Ben - As far as I can tell, there's no bolt holes in it either. I viewed [this video for timing belt removal](https://youtu.be/YUcWsiDfFxQ) for a 97 Corolla, which I'd venture to assume is the same engine (correct me if I'm wrong). There's a really good view of the crank gear at [4:58 into the video](https://youtu.be/YUcWsiDfFxQ?t=4m58s).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I must of been thinking of a different engine.

Answer (score 1):

SI says to use two flathead screwdrivers with rags providing a cushion to work the sprocket off.

Place them in between the sprocket and oil pump housing and carefully pry the sprocket loose.

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: I would definitely suggest to use a proper sprocket puller as from my experience with 1.6 early mx5 engine I was trying to pull the sprocket out without a puller and ended up braking the sprocket lip

Comment: Sometimes you can heat the sprocket to make it swell a bit then it will slide off easily. They are not press fit.

Answer (score 0):

i just did mine.tough to get it out, but i did get it out.This is what you have to do.There are no pulley that can go in to grab the gear.what you have to do is use a propane torch heat it up, then have a soft hammer i.e. a brass hammer, tap the edge of the gear rotate the crank shaft ,and tap with the hammer.you also have to put wd40 oil on the gear and shaft.the edge of the gear will get routed,but don't worry.after you get the gear outtake a chain saw file (round)then filed back the grov where the timing belt is going to seat.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to remove the old crank seal, and put a new one.
The tools you need is a self taping sheet metal screw because the crankshaft seal has heath sides.2)a screw driver 3)a pliers.
Use the screw, screw the edge of the old seal, screw it toll you get 1 or 2 thread, then use the pliers and grab the screw and pull.Vola the seal will pop out.
Then clean the hole wipe it clean, then add grease or oil on both the crank shaft and seal.Slide the seal until it reach the opening, then find any pipe bigger than the inner diameter of the seal, use the pipe and tap the seal in.And it's done